# How to cover setInterval in the unit test case in javascript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, setinterval

Hi I am write a unit test case of this function. When I run this function from the unit test case then it covers all statements but `setInterval` complete lines are not covered.

Does anyone know how to cover it in javascript? I am using mocha.

```
const open = async function (config) {

    ...... set of lines..

    let retryIn = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
            client = await connect(config);
            clearInterval(retryIn);
            return client;
        } catch (err) {
           //error
        }
    }, 20000);

};
```

I am simply calling it like this

```
it("###test", async () => {
        open(config);
    });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778661/mocha-and-chai-test-fails-when-testing-function-with-setinterval

Comment: Not related to your question. But what exactly should the `setInterval` do in your case? This construct looks completely wrong. If you abuse a thrown exception of `connect` to force a re-try of the connection after 20sec, then you really should change that, especially if that code runs in node. An unhandled rejection of a Promise will exit node applications in future.

Comment: @NSharma It still looks extremely suspicious. Because then your code would only make _"sense"_ if `await connect` waits more then 20sec, but even then it looks like a wrong handling of an error case.

Comment: @t.niese see this updated code, this is my code, `connect` method throws an error

Comment: @NSharma Not related to your question but is `connnect` tries to connect to a socket ?! if this is the case , then [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304996/javascript-using-promises-on-websocket/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should never use `setInterval` in the case where you want to retry a task that has failed. You should use `setTimeout` instead.

Besides that, you cannot return a value from a classical callback base function like `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. So in its current form, the promise returned when calling `open` will be resolved before any connection is made.

With `await`/`async` you can create a clean and simple setup for such a situation:

```js
function wait(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds))
}

async function connect() {
  throw new Error('failed')
}

async function open(config) {
  let client;

  while (client === undefined /* || retries > maxRetries*/ ) {
    try {
      client = await connect(config);
    } catch (err) {
      // if connection failed due to an error, wait n seconds and retry
      console.log('failed wait 2 seconds for reconnect');
      await wait(2000)
      // ++retries
    }
  }


  if (!client) {
    throw new Error('connection failed due to max number of retries reached.')
  }
  
  return client
}


async function main() {
  let connection = await open()
}

main().catch(err => console.log(err))
```

You can further extend this snippet by adding a retry limit. See the comments for a rough idea on how that can be achieved.

To test the above code, you would write:

```
it("###test", function() {
  return open(config);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted an answer about fake timers and then deleted it , The answer was correct so I re-posted again.

You can use [`sinonjs`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/fake-timers/) to create fake timers

> Fake timers are synchronous implementations of setTimeout and friends
>   that Sinon.JS can overwrite the global functions with to allow you to
>   more easily test code using them

But from your code, it seems you are trying to test async code, in mocha, this can be achieved like this

```
describe('somthing', () => {
  it('the result is 2', async () => {
    const x = await add(1, 1)
    expect(x).to.equal(4);
  });
});
```

With something closer to your code

```
async function open() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('done')
    }, 1000);
  });
};

describe('somthing', () => {
  it('###test', async () => {
    const x = await open()
    chai.expect(x).to.equal("done");
  });
});
```

Comment: can you suggest with my example ?

Comment: @NSharma sure , first please post a working code for `open`

Comment: ok lets take an example `const open = async function (config) {

    let retryIn = setInterval(async () => {
        try {
            return "hello";
        } catch (err) {
           //error
        }
    }, 20000);

};`

Comment: @NSharma even this code does not make any sense, you need to return a value from `setInterval` , this is not possible

Comment: @NSharma Actually I think you need `setTimeout` here not `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap to `Promise`

```
const open = async function (config) {
    ...... set of lines..
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let retryIn = setInterval(async () => {
        client = await connect(asConfigParam);
        clearInterval(retryIn);
        return client;
      }, 20000);
      return resolve(retryIn);
    });
};


it("###test", async () => {
        const result = await open(config);
        console.log('result', result)
});
```

Comment: This does not make sense, what do you think that `result` would be and how that would help to do unit tests?